# Unexpected error while running parlai_chat_task_demo python3 parlai_test_script.py

Tags: mephisto

I receive an error while running an example code from https://github.com/facebookresearch/Mephisto/blob/main/examples/parlai_chat_task_demo/README.md
`python3 parlai_test_script.py`

I try to run an example script.
The error:

```
hydra.errors.ConfigCompositionException: Error merging mephisto/blueprint=parlai_chat
```

May be someone have already faced the same problem and fixed it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer! When you install parlai with pip, hydra-core-1.0.7 is a dependency and this old version of package is the reason of my error. You need to install hydra-core-1.1.1.

I hope that it will be useful for somebody.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).